# .NET Core - Post request not waiting for OnAuthorization to finish

Tags: asp.net-core, authorization

I have a **request filter** that runs on **every request to check for security id's**

but I noticed that my **POST requests functions were not waiting for it to run**

for instance I have an **upload entry point** that is **already running before the OnAuthorization has finished checking the request**

my request filter is added to startup.cs with

```
services.AddScoped<CheckRequestFilter>();
```

I tried adding **[Authorize] && [ServiceFilter(typeof(CheckRequestFilter))]** directly above the request function but the request starts running and is not waiting for authorization

```
[HttpPost, DisableRequestSizeLimit]
[Route("uploadCsv")]
[Authorize]
[ServiceFilter(typeof(CheckRequestFilter))]
public IActionResult Upload()
{
    try
    {
        var file = Request.Form.Files[0];
        ... // doing stuffs with uploaded file
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError(ex.Message);
        return StatusCode(500, $"Internal server error: {ex}");
    }
}
```

since my **filter** is checking the body of the requests, it **is not done while the requests itself is already being processed**

```
public async void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
{
    var req = context.HttpContext.Request;

    //------------------------------------- check id's in request body
    req.EnableBuffering();

    using (var reader = new StreamReader(...))
    {
        var bodyString = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
        if(bodyString!="")
        {
            // checking id's in the body
            ...
            if (notFailed)
            {
                req.Body.Position = 0;
                return;                 // return without error
            }
        }

        // failing
        req.Body.Position = 0;
        context.Result = new CustomUnauthorizedResult("Authorization failed."); // return a 401 code
    }    
}
```

**I expect my OnAuthorization to return BEFORE the request itself is executed**
otherwise what would be the point

thanks for helping me on this

Comment: According to your description, I suggest you could consider using custom middleware to achieve your requirement. This will fired before all the filter in the application. More details about how to create it, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/write?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

Comment: afaik it's a custom middleware

Comment: No filter is not a middleware, the filter will run after the middleware.